# Is there in GSON annotation with opposite meaning than @Expose (like @XmlTransient for Jaxb)?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jaxb, gson

If I want to exclude some fields from serialization process I should to mark all **other** fields by `@Expose` annotation.  Sometimes it is not enough flexibly. In jaxb exist annotation `@XmlTransient`. I mark field which shoudn't serialize and it is work good. Is there in `GSON` analog of this annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java keyword `transient` on a field to have it excluded in Gson's serialization to JSON.

Comment: Yes, but I want have different view for json serialization and xml serialization.

Comment: @gstackoverflow - What are you using for XML serialization?

Comment: I use jaxB and @XmlTransient  annotation

Comment: @gstackoverflow - If you want to have a different XML serialization then you can annotate the `transient` field with `@XmlElement`.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. But anyway it is looks like dog-nail.

Comment: I hope to find a resolving in GSON